# How to change font size of uitableview cell after everything has loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Is it possible to change the font size of a cell in a tableview outside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Basically I am trying to change the font size of a specific cell in the table on a timer in `viewDidLoad`. So once the view is totally loaded a timer will start then after x seconds the font size of one cell in the table will change?

Answer (score 3):

You can, use below code

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathOfYourCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where abouts would I put the font size code?

Comment: @DonPeters I think you should use property for your specific cell. Like this; 

@property(nonatomic,strong) YourCellClass * cell;

... 
cell.customLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontSize:12];
...

then you should use code above to reload your specific cell.

Comment: Sorry, I am a little confused, is this for static cells? At the moment all my rows in the table are populated dynamically.